# Committing transactions in Oracle Interactive XA datasource

Tags: java, oracle, interactive

I am using oracle Interactive non XA datasource in oracle, in a loop i am inserting records in 
a table. But table gets locks.

Do we need to commit transactions in  Interactive non XA datasources.

Comment: it simply depends on whether transaction is started.  Your question is not clear enough.  Show us some simplified code on how you are retrieveing connection from datasource, and how you are inserting data.

Comment: Here is how i get connection private void initializeConnection() throws SQLException {
  if (con == null) {
   DataSource ds = (DataSource) JndiHelper.lookupNonEjb(poolName);
   con = ds.getConnection();
  }
 }

 public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
  initializeConnection();
  return con;
 }